# How to schedule Rails rake task on Azure App Service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, azure-web-app-service

I need to schedule a rake task on an app that's deployed to Azure App Service.

I'm looking for something like a cron job or Heroku Scheduler.

I just need to run a simple command like this:

```
$ bundle exec rake my_task
```

But the documentation in this area isn't clear.

I read about [WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) but I'm not sure if that's what I'm after.  I also found  [ACR Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-overview), but that seems like it's meant for container maintenance/telemetry.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you considered using something like the `whenever` gem? https://github.com/javan/whenever — I know it's not a feature from Azure, but it would prevent any vendor lock-in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) , you can use the GUI initially to put the cron expression that represents the frequency of your execution. So create your rake task as you usually would do and set up using the User Interface:

[image]

In case you are not familiar with CRON expressions you can check [this CRON builder](https://crontab.guru/)

Comment: This is a good suggestion for windows-based apps, however, it looks like MS doesn't support it on Linux-based containers.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't - not on App Service for Linux.

#### No Web Job Support for Linux

Web jobs are not supported for Linux as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#overview

I had this same challenge for a Rails App, where I wanted to execute a rake task in the fashion, e.g. `heroku run rake db:migrate`. There's no easy way to do this on App Service.

#### Workaround: use an Azure Function

When I contacted the team about this problem, the suggestion they gave was to use an Azure function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function

That could work. But it would be terrible to have to manage multiple deployments *and* configuration of the same code for the same environment.